# Log output of JVisualVM

Tags: jmx, jvisualvm

Are there any tools that can connect to a remote JVM and log to a file the information which is displayed in the Monitor tab of JVisualVM or the Overview tab of JConsole?

I am aware of applications such as AppDynamics etc - this is for a little performance test for a machine which is already set up - even though we have AppDynamics licences, using AppDynamics isn't really an option in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use tracer plugin where u can import the information in csv/html/xml.This is for jvisualvm
http://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html